# MySQL database - Got error 28 from storage engine while accessing from webmin

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to access an MySQL database from the webmin console. But I'm unable to access the db, as it throws following error message:

```
SQL select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = ? 
failed : Got error 28 from storage engine
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you try googling "Got error 28 from storage engine"?, I found pages of answers saying check that there is enough disk space

Comment: k thanks for ur reply, how can increase disk space here?

Comment: 'I think we're going to need a bigger disk...'

Comment: possible duplicate of [1030 Got error 28 from storage engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine)

Answer (score 25):

Check your disk space usage.

I also faced the same problem.  I fixed by moving files into another disk.

If you are using Linux OS.  You can check the disk usage by using the command:

```
> df -k

    Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/xvda1             8256952   7857928         0 100% /
    udev                    860884         4    860880   1% /dev
    tmpfs                   347492       188    347304   1% /run
    none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
    none                    868724         0    868724   0% /run/shm
    /dev/xvdb            350891748    199364 332868104   1% /mnt
```

And I moved some files from /dev/xvda1 ->  /dev/xvdb   partition.

And checked the disk usage.

```
> df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952   2520216   5317308  33% /
udev                    860884         4    860880   1% /dev
tmpfs                   347492       188    347304   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    868724         0    868724   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb            350891748    415456 332652012   1% /mnt
```

Now MySQL server working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is a disk space problem, but it could by masquerade. I suggest open 2 consoles and run in one of them

```
watch -n1 "df -h"
```

and on the other try to reproduce the error, at the same time look at the first console.
In my case /tmp was at 35% (1G), it goes to 100%, and when the command finish went back to 35%.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my own case, It was a masquerade. I host the site with Siteground, and when I used their SuperCacher to flush the system, everything started working again.
I am just adding this answer for anyone in