# mysql on SonarQube is bloated

Tags: java, mysql, database, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 4.5 with mysql.
Here's the part in the system information:

```
   Version  4.5
   Database MySQL 5.5.40
   Database URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?   useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
   Database Login   sonar
   Database Driver  MySQL Connector Java mysql-connector-java-5.1.27 ( Revision: alexander.soklakov@oracle.com-20131021093118-gtm1bh1vb450xipt )
```

When running the Hudson build I get an exception, which among other says:

> SQL: select           c.id,     c.kee as kee,     c.issue_key as issueKey,     c.user_login as userLogin,     c.change_type as changeType,     c.change_data as changeData,     c.created_at as createdAt,     c.updated_at as updatedAt,     c.issue_change_creation_date as issueChangeCreationDate         from issue_changes c     inner join issues i on i.kee = c.issue_key     inner join (select p.id,p.kee from projects p where (p.root_id=? and p.qualifier <> 'BRC') or (p.id=?)) p on p.id=i.component_id      WHERE  c.change_type=?       and i.status <> 'CLOSED'      order by c.issue_change_creation_date asc
>
> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Got error 28 from storage engine

I have set up the **Delete all snapshots after** to 10.
When I go to sonar-home/data, I see a huge file *sonar.h2.db*

1. can I delete it?
2. Where's the mySQL data located?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you should not have `sonar.h2.db` files in `$SONAR_HOME/data` folder (this is only when you run SonarQube with the built-in H2 DB for test purposes).

The error you get from MySQL tells you that you don't have enough space, see [1030 Got error 28 from storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine).

Comment: So I can delete those files. OK
I know that I don't enough space. Do you know where usually MySQL keeps the data?

Comment: Please make an effort and search on Internet, there are plenty of answers to your question, including some on Stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091350/where-does-mysql-store-database-files).