# Got error 28 from storage engine while running large UNION query

Tags: mysql, database

I am running into error `Error Code: 1030. Got error 28 from storage engine` when running the following large `UNION` query ,when I run the queries which I am UNION'ing seperately they run fine..looking at other [1030 Got error 28 from storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine) posts the issue seems to be with `Database Server because it is out of disk space` or `/tmp` folder is out of space..my question is why only on the large `UNION` query?

```
   select distinct cl.change_list_id, cl.change_list, cr.change_request, compL.component_id ,
     compL.component_label_id, compL.component_label, intS.integration_status, lr.ec_job_link, 
    lr.submitted_by, lr.submission_time, lr.completion_time, lr.lookahead_run_status 
    from change_lists as cl, component_labels_change_lists as clcl, component_labels as compL, 
    component_label_details as cld, integration_status as intS, change_lists_change_requests as clcr, 
    change_requests as cr, lookahead_run_change_list as lrcl, lookahead_run as lr where cl.change_list 
    in ( 2033001 ) and clcl.change_list_id = cl.change_list_id and 
    clcl.component_label_id = compL.component_label_id and cld.component_label_id = compL.component_label_id 
    and intS.integration_status_id = cld.integration_status_id and clcr.change_list_id = cl.change_list_id 
    and cr.change_request_id = clcr.change_request_id and lrcl.change_list_id=cl.change_list_id 
    and lrcl.lookahead_run_id=lr.lookahead_run_id and lr.lookahead_run_status='complete' 


    UNION 

select distinct cl.change_list_id, cl.change_list, cr.change_request, compL.component_id , 
    compL.component_label_id, compL.component_label, intS.integration_status, lr.ec_job_link, 
    lr.submitted_by, lr.submission_time, lr.completion_time, lr.lookahead_run_status from change_lists as cl, 
    component_labels_change_lists as clcl, component_labels as compL, component_label_details as cld, 
    integration_status as intS, change_lists_change_requests as clcr, change_requests as cr, 
    lookahead_run_change_list as lrcl, lookahead_run as lr where cr.change_request in ( 2033001 ) and 
    clcr.change_request_id = cr.change_request_id and cl.change_list_id = clcr.change_list_id and 
    clcl.change_list_id = cl.change_list_id and clcl.component_label_id = compL.component_label_id and 
    cld.component_label_id = compL.component_label_id and intS.integration_status_id = cld.integration_status_id 
    and lrcl.change_list_id=cl.change_list_id and lrcl.lookahead_run_id=lr.lookahead_run_id 
    and lr.lookahead_run_status='complete'
```

Comment: ...because only the large UNION query requires so much temp space as to use up the device.  MySQL has to cache the entire results of both subqueries in order to create the complete results (i.e. it must execute and store the result of every subquery in the UNION).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1030 Got error 28 from storage engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine)