# Is there a way to access a specific coding sequence of a gene of interest on ENSEMBL in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to find a way to retrieve the coding sequence (CDS) of a specific gene of interest and load it into R. I tried my luck with the BioMart package, but it doesn't let me specify which gene I am interested in.

Any help is appreciated!

Best, 
Heiko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(biomaRt)
library(Biostrings)
mart <- useMart("ensembl", dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
cds_seq = getSequence(id = "APOE", 
                   type = "hgnc_symbol", 
                   seqType = "cdna", 
                   mart = mart)
```

We can translate the CDS:

```
AAs = sapply(cds_seq$coding,function(i)if(i=="Sequence unavailable"){NA}else{translate(DNAString(i))})
```

Get peptide sequence:

```
pep_seq = getSequence(id = "APOE", 
                   type = "hgnc_symbol", 
                   seqType = "peptide", 
                   mart = mart)
```

And check they are similar:

```
lapply(which(pep_seq$peptide!="Sequence unavailable"),function(i){
pep_seq$peptide[i] == as.character(AAs[[i]])
})

[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to get the refseq, do:

```
cds_seq = getSequence(id = "NM_000041", 
                      type = "refseq_mrna", 
                      seqType = "coding", 
                      mart = mart)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! If I run

mart <- useMart("ensembl", dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
cds_seq = getSequence(id = "APOE", 
                   type = "hgnc_symbol", 
                   seqType = "cdna", 
                   mart = mart)

it gives me a list with several cDNAs in it... Is there a way to specify and only load one specific refseq transcript?

Comment: @Heiko, you have to know the refseq mrna id, see above edited answer

Comment: cool, glad you got it going. If you feel that the answer has solved your problem, you can consider accepting it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks again, StupidWolf!

Comment: Dear StupidWolf,

Sometimes I get an error saying:

Error in .processResults(postRes, mart = mart, sep = sep, fullXmlQuery = fullXmlQuery,  : Query ERROR: caught BioMart::Exception::Database: Error during query execution: Got error 28 from storage engine

Do you have any idea what that means? I does not produce my cds_seq file then...

Comment: are you outta disk space? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine

Comment: Hey StupidWolf, I was able to solve the issue by changing the host... Thanks though!